# Find and replace multiple words in a column in excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub xLator2()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long
Dim from(), too()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '   contains the data
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2") '   contains the translation table

s2.Activate

N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim from(1 To N)
ReDim too(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

s1.Activate

For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

I am using above code to find and replace multiple words (in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet 2") in below mentioned sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15TRLccDr_EAR8s78u-WGSkGpAecBf42_lhRkjCev_WE/edit?usp=sharing

However when I apply this in another sheet (as mentioned below) for another data then code fails i.e. I get distorted words in sheet1:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ba9pQDjMPWJd4YFpGffhtVcHxml0LdUUVQ0prrOEUY/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me out so that I can replace words in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet2"
Note: Above links have been given of google spreadsheet however I am having problem in Excel 2007 sheet.
I request you to help me out by providing whole revised code as I am not good in VBA

Answer (score 0):

In Excel I have found some problem.
**Fisrt** it to refer always to a Cell with the prefix:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells ...
```

**Second**. The strange words appear because Find/Replace substitute portion of words. If you don't want use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i), LookAt:=xlWhole
```

**Third**. The Find/Replace work on ALL the Sheet1. If you want only the column "A":

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Selection.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i), LookAt:=xlWhole
Next i
```